# Javascript on JetBrains IDE: type-hinting the autonomous custom element instance

Tags: javascript, ide, phpstorm, jsdoc, type-hinting

Consider the following:

```
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {}
customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElement);
/** @type {MyCustomElement} */
const myCustomElement = document.createElement('my-custom-element');
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `myCustomElement` would be an instance of `MyCustomElement` at runtime (a derivation of [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)); but, [type-hinting](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wikis/TagType.wiki) the `myCustomElement` makes the JetBrains IDE of PhpStorm to complain:

> *Initializer type `HTMLElement` is not assignable to variable type `MyCustomElement`*

Surprisingly, the IDE is totally fine on the built-in types:

```
/** @type {HTMLDivElement} */
const myDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

So, what should I do to have *the very appropriate "typing hints" to the IDE (not using `*`)* while having the warning resolved?!

---

*I could've instantiate the `myCustomElement` using the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator; and it seems to work, but there is no reference on the differences between the approaches (on whether to use `new` or to use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), and why or why-not to choose one over the other?!)*

Answer (score 2):

Closure doesn't understand that you're instantiating an instance of MyCustomElement from the `document.createElement` because it does not understand `customElements.define`'s implications* on its internal type system you're creating an HTMLElement with a tag name of "my-custom-element".

What you'll likely want to do is cast the result of the `createElement` function (`HTMLElement`) as `MyCustomElement`:

```
/** @type {MyCustomElement} */
const myCustomElement = /** @type {MyCustomElement} */ (document.createElement('my-custom-element'));
```

*: As far as I know; there is no evidence that they intend to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The IDE surly doesn't understand the logical details of the API. What the IDE _should_ know about is the fact that my class of `MyCustomElement` is inheriting from `HTMLElement`, and thus it's essentially an `HTMLElement`, but still complains; while it knows the `HTMLDivElement`, for example, is inheriting from `HTMLElement` and thus it's actually an `HTMLElement`, and doesn't complain; It's weird that it does not apply the very same concept to the user-defined classes but does it for the built-ins. However, the _"casting"_ workaround seems to remedy the issue.